# Getting the orginal value of variable after entering a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm making a simple script that iterates through the files in the current directories,
the `$1` is for a size parameter and the others `$1,$2 .....` are for the manipulated files and set for the file names.
the problem is after using the `for` loop the variable are losing their value and start with integers like 1,2,3, and the script doesn't work unless I use files named as 1,2,3,....
How can I keep the original values?
ex:
 ./script 50 my_first_file .....

```
#!/bin/bash
size=$1
allfiles=$#
shift
#here the value of the $1 is "my_first_file"
  for ((i = 1 ; i < allfiles ; i++))
  do
  #here the value of the $1 = 1
  done
```

Comment: What do you mean, "losing their value"? You haven't shown anything in the loop that would change the value of the positional arguments.

Comment: If you want to iterate over the arguments, it's just `for f in "$@"; do ...; done`.

Comment: @chepner is there any difference between $# and $@? I already iterated through the arguments using $# but as I mentioned the arguments value reset and start from 1 according to the loop

Comment: `$#`: number of arguments.  `$@`: all the arguments.

Comment: @M.S.S.SE You didn't iterate over the arguments. If you run `set a b c d e`, you'll see that `echo "$#"` outputs 5, while `echo "$@"` outputs each of `a` et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `for` loop with integers, you can loop on arguments directly like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

size="$1"
allfiles=$#
shift

counter=1
for i in "$@"
do
    echo "$counter= $i"
    (( counter = counter + 1 ))
done

echo "size= $size"
```

This will show you each argument in sequence.
If you need to show or use the position of each argument, you can use a counter.

If I call this: `script.bash 25 a b c`
The output is:

```
1= a
2= b
3= c
size= 25
```

Comment: When you use `$@`, you should double-quote it (i.e. use `"$@"`) to prevent weird parsing of some characters.

Comment: so now what is the best way to check whether the file if exist or not?
if [ -f $i ];then
   #some commands
fi

is that correct? I tried it but had no result I mean the condition was ignored

Comment: @M.S.S.SE Again, you should double-quote the variable (`if [ -f "$i" ];then`), but that's probably not the problem here (probably). Without more info, it's hard to say what else might be wrong. Putting `set -x` before the problem section will print commands (or their equivalents) as they're executed, which often clarifies what's going on. BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Comment: The only way to help is for you to start a new question.  In that question you must put your code, sample directory and files structure, what you expect your code to do, what it is doing now.  Then we can replicate your test setup, try your code and propose ameliorations.  But do not start a new question in the comments of a previously closed one.

Comment: The if condition is working great now.. but I have a problem in the loop, if I entered only one argument (size) and want to check for the $# (if user entered at least one file) after shifting as a user input prompt to input at least one file after the argument size.. but the $# value will be 1 instead of 2.
how can I decrease the loop such as (for i in "$@" - 1) without using shift

Answer (score 1):

Another option is just use a short hand of looping through the files.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

size=$1
shift

counter=1

for f; do
  printf '%d. %s\n' "$((counter++))" "$f"
done

printf 'size=%s\n' "$size"
```